# Corda - How to migrate Cordapp build using v1.0 of Corda platform to v3.0+?

Tags: corda

I am using release-v1 of Corda for building a CorDapp.

The CorDapp has four nodes - Controller node (provides network map service and validating notary service), "node A", "node B" and "node C". Following are the flows defined in the app -

Flow 1: "Node A" sends a trade request to "Node B". "Node C" is also notified.

Flow 2: "Node B" approves the trade request, self-signs it, gets signature from A and closes the trade. "Node C" is also notified.

I want to migrate the CorDapp to v3.0+.

I have couple of questions -

1. Can I get link to documentation of the migration steps?
2. Will the code used for the flows be affected on migration?

Comment: do you have a network running your application or is this just something you are developing locally? If it is just locally, I would just up your app to v4 (or 3) and fix any errors. I am not sure of the migrations steps of v1 since that is an older version (not sure if the apis were stable in that release).

Comment: Can you please provide a generalized list of steps for migration?

Comment: https://docs.corda.net/app-upgrade-notes.html but these are around upgrading from 3 to 4. Some might apply but don't know which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation at the following link provides instructions for upgrading CorDapps from V1.0 to V3+.

**https://docs.corda.net/upgrade-notes.html**

The document proposes step-wise upgradation i.e.

1. First migrate app from V1.0 to V2.0
2. Next migrate app from V2.0 to V3.0
3. Next migrate app from V3.0 to V3.1
4. Next migrate app from V3.1 to V3.2
5. Next migrate app from V3.2 to V3.3